# Set notification at specific time Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set notification at the time (hour, minute) that I set. But It show error:

[image]

```
  func notification(story: Story) {
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents.init()
    dateComponents.weekday = 5
    dateComponents.hour = story.remindeAtHour
    dateComponents.minute = story.remindeAtMinute
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertAction = "Title"
    notification.alertBody = "It's time to take a photo"
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
    notification.fireDate = dateComponents.calendar
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
  }
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? It is pretty clear what you are doing wrong.  Have you read the documentation for NSDateComponents?  Specifically the calendar and date properties.

Comment: I know that. But how to set time for fire at a specific time?

Comment: It looks like the answer below can be accepted, Khuong. Would you do so? We would rather that questions are not abandoned here if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul w points out in his comment, the error message is telling you what's wrong.

You need to set the notification's fireDate property to a date (An `NSDate`). You need a method that will convert date components to an `NSDate`. How about the NSCalendar method `dateFromComponents:`?

Comment: How about the NSDateComponents property `date`?

Comment: Is notification.fireDate = dateComponents.date will fine?

Comment: I have tried notification.fireDate = dateComponents.date. But It didn't work.